# Transition between room effects in Resonance Audio?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fmod, resonance-audio

I'm using GoogleVR Resonance Audio with FMOD Studio and Unity and trying out room effects.

The effects of room volumes seem to work fine, but the transition when going in or out of a volume is instant and extremely jarring and immersion-breaking. Instantly sounds around you sound completely different when moving your head a fraction to one side or the other.

Is there any way to make the transition gradual, for example by interpolating between multiple room presets, fading one out and the other in?

If not, what are recommended ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The way I've been reading to do this is to use reverb probes, as you can have multiple probes to represent different positions in the room.

The probes are similar to rooms, except they use rays to get a feel of the space from the position of the gameobject, and seem to be pretty versatile.

To give an example: [A picture of room with a reverb probe in one Room, a probe in the doorway, and a probe in the next room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnlrX.png)

The player will hear the room acoustics of the first room when they're inside probe 1, when they enter the doorway probe they hear a mixture, and then all of the next room after that.

This smooths out the transitions quite well, as it probes everything in both rooms from gradual shifts in position. This is suggested in the Developer Guide [here](https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/unity/developer-guide#placing_a_reverb_probe).

I hope this helped! :)

Comment: Ah, this seems to be a feature that is available in Resonance Audio for Unity, but not in Resonance Audio for FMOD in Unity. The latter is documented here and there is no Reverb Probe unfortunately. https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/fmod/game-engine-integration

Comment: Ouch, you're right, that's a pity.

The only workaround I can think of is to do the reverb probes in Unity, but that would mean presumably having the master channel inside Unity's mixer as opposed to fmod and I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: When using FMOD Studio, sound doesn't go through Unitys audio system at all (it's entirely disabled), so unfortunately using Unity's mixer is not an option to use as a workaround.